# php mail function

Tags: php

I have a form in my web site. When user enters data it should reach to my gmail  id. I tried many things but it is not working.

http://pastebin.com/xABBduyB

This is the settings in php.ini

```
SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
sendmail_from = myname@gmail.com
SMTP_PORT = 465
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution for you could be to use [phpmailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) library

This is the sample googled code to do that:

```
$mail->Mailer = "smtp";  
$mail->Host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";  
$mail->Port = 465;  
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // turn on SMTP authentication  
$mail->Username = "username@gmail.com"; // SMTP username  
$mail->Password = "password"; // SMTP password
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP's `mail` function works only with standard SMTP, but to access the Gmail server, you need to use SMTP over SSL. You can find an example of how to do this [over here](http://email.about.com/od/emailprogrammingtips/qt/PHP_Email_SMTP_Authentication.htm).

Comment: I am using like this http://pastebin.com/Jii79RUt   I am getting this error  Fatal error: Class 'Mail' not found in C:\wamp\www\silverage_website\fedmail.php on line 21

Comment: Should i install any pear packages.

Comment: @user506539: Yes, it requires the Mail package, which you can [find here](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail/download).